# Reducing RAM and CPU usage on a specific manually selected process

Tags: memory, performance, cpu-usage

I'm using a very nice desktop software for Gmail (and other email providers): [Mailbird](http://www.getmailbird.com). But it consumes too much RAM and CPU, so I have to close it sometimes.

I'd like to know if there is any software which allows the user to force a limit of CPU and RAM usage (sending the rest of data to the pagination file) when it stays minimized in the taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CleanMem](http://www.pcwintech.com/cleanmem) can reduce the ram usage to the minimum on an specific select process.

But it will reduce the ram usage no matter if it is idle (so minimized) or not. I requested to clean the RAM only if the program is idle here: http://forums.pcwintech.com/index.php/topic,4410.0.html

Comment: maybe useful for you too, @magicandre1981? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can trim the WorkingSet with [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/). Make a right click on the process, select "Misc" and "Reduce Working Set".

Comment: I did it, but I don't see any change. Should appear aconfiguration windows after clicking the "Reduce Working Set" option?

Comment: no, the command is executed directly. Look at the "Working Set" column.

Comment: I don't see any column with that name. I also looked in the view menu and the options trying to find it. There isn't any "check tic" after pushing "Miscellaneous-Reduce Working Set". Maybe it doesn't work with .NET software?

Comment: enable the column first.

Comment: OK. They way to enable the column is right click at the title of any column. It was I didn't find yesterday.

Comment: It works, but if we restore the program back, the memory usage will become high again. **We must click on "Reduce Working Set" manually every time we minimize the window**. So let me google "reduce working set" to try to find an "automatic" software. Thanks man!

Comment: this is by design. When the programs need the data they are read from the pagefile again.

Comment: you are right, but the ideal would be a software which detect when the program is minimized, and then call to "Reduce Working Set". Maybe, it could be do with [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/) or some other scripting software.

Comment: you should contact the support of the tool and report the high memory and cpu usage so that they fix it.

Comment: I already did. Actually, somebody else did it before than me. I just comment his ticket to show my interest.

Comment: ok, now you must wait for a fix.

Comment: I tried using Process Hacker to Reduce Working Set to prevent VSDC Video Editor from sucking up all available RAM and then crashing. It did not work.